# How can I get the row of a frame on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to get the row index of a frame on my code but for some reason the `.grid_info()` is returning

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pedro\Documents\jobs\Analista\digitrainer_v0.2c.py", line 113, in <module>
    row = info['row']
KeyError: 'row'
[Finished in 426ms]
```

Here's a section of my code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

buttonFrame = Frame(root)

def AddRemove(button_id):
    if button_id == 1: # addPlayer
        # Get the row number of "buttonFrame" with "get_info()" / Pega o numero da linha de "buttonFrame" com "get_info()"
        info = buttonFrame.grid_info()
        row = info['row']
        # Move frame to next row / Move frame para a próxima linha
        info['row'] = row + 1
        buttonFrame.grid(**info)
    elif button_id == 2: # removePlayer
        # Get the row number of "buttonFrame" with "get_info()" / Pega o numero da linha de "buttonFrame" com "get_info()"
        info = buttonFrame.grid_info()
        row = info['row']
        # Move frame to previous row / Move frame para a linha anterior
        info['row'] = row - 1
        buttonFrame.grid(**info)

# Button to add players / Botão para adicionar jogadores
addPlayer = Button(buttonFrame, text="Adicionar jogador", command=AddRemove(1))
addPlayer.grid(column=1, row=0)

# Button to remove players / Botão para remover jogadores
removePlayer = Button(buttonFrame, text="Remover jogador", command=AddRemove(2))
removePlayer.grid_forget()

buttonFrame.grid(column=1, row=8)

root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: code after adding `lambda:` to button's command

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

titleFrame = Frame(root)

player1Frame = Frame(root)
player2Frame = Frame(root)
player3Frame = Frame(root)
player4Frame = Frame(root)
player5Frame = Frame(root)
player6Frame = Frame(root)
player7Frame = Frame(root)
player8Frame = Frame(root)
player9Frame = Frame(root)
player10Frame = Frame(root)
player11Frame = Frame(root)
player12Frame = Frame(root)
player13Frame = Frame(root)
player14Frame = Frame(root)

buttonFrame = Frame(root)

class Players():

    # Function for the "addPlayer" and "removePlayer" buttons / Função para os botões "addPlayer" e "removePlayer"
    def AddRemove(button_id):
        if button_id == 1: # addPlayer
            # Get the row number of "buttonFrame" with "get_info()" / Pega o numero da linha de "buttonFrame" com "get_info()"
            info = buttonFrame.grid_info()
            row = info['row']
            # Move frame to next row / Move frame para a próxima linha
            info['row'] = row + 1
            buttonFrame.grid(**info)
            # Checks current row and shows player frame / Verifica a linha atual e mostra o frame de jogador
            if row == 9:
                player8Frame.grid(column=1, row=row, pady=1)
                removePlayer = Button(buttonFrame)
                removePlayer.grid(column=1, row=0)

            elif row == 10:
                player9Frame.grid(column=1, row=row, pady=1)

            elif row == 11:
                player10Frame.grid(column=1, row=row, pady=1)

            elif row == 12:
                player11Frame.grid(column=1, row=row, pady=1)

            elif row == 13:
                player12Frame.grid(column=1, row=row, pady=1)

            elif row == 14:
                player13Frame.grid(column=1, row=row, pady=1)
                
            elif row == 15:
                player14Frame.grid(column=1, row=row, pady=1)
                addPlayer = Button(buttonFrame).grid_forget()

        elif button_id == 2: # removePlayer
            # Get the row number of "buttonFrame" with "get_info()" / Pega o numero da linha de "buttonFrame" com "get_info()"
            info = buttonFrame.grid_info()
            row = info['row']
            # Move frame to previous row / Move frame para a linha anterior
            info['row'] = row - 1
            buttonFrame.grid(**info)
            # Checks current row and hides player frame / Verifica a linha atual e esconde o frame de jogador
            if row == 9:
                player8Frame.forget()
                removePlayer = Button(buttonFrame).grid_forget()

            elif row == 10:
                player9Frame.forget()

            elif row == 11:
                player10Frame.forget()

            elif row == 12:
                player11Frame.forget()

            elif row == 13:
                player12Frame.forget()

            elif row == 14:
                player13Frame.forget()

            elif row == 15:
                player14Frame.forget()
    
    playersTitle = Label(titleFrame, text="Jogadores", justify=CENTER).grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky=NS, ipadx=45)
    # Players' numbers and names / Numeros e nomes dos jogadores
    pnum1 = Label(player1Frame, text="1").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum2 = Label(player2Frame, text="2").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum3 = Label(player3Frame, text="3").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum4 = Label(player4Frame, text="4").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum5 = Label(player5Frame, text="5").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum6 = Label(player6Frame, text="6").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum7 = Label(player7Frame, text="7").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum8 = Label(player8Frame, text="8").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum9 = Label(player9Frame, text="9").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum10 = Label(player10Frame, text="10").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum11 = Label(player11Frame, text="11").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum12 = Label(player12Frame, text="12").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum13 = Label(player13Frame, text="13").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)
    pnum14 = Label(player14Frame, text="14").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1)

    player1 = Entry(player1Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player2 = Entry(player2Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player3 = Entry(player3Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player4 = Entry(player4Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player5 = Entry(player5Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player6 = Entry(player6Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player7 = Entry(player7Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player8 = Entry(player8Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player9 = Entry(player9Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player10 = Entry(player10Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player11 = Entry(player11Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player12 = Entry(player12Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player13 = Entry(player13Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    player14 = Entry(player14Frame).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1)
    
    # Button to add players / Botão para adicionar jogadores
    addPlayer = Button(buttonFrame, text="Adicionar jogador", command=lambda: AddRemove(1))
    addPlayer.grid(column=1, row=0)

    # Button to remove players / Botão para remover jogadores
    removePlayer = Button(buttonFrame, text="Remover jogador", command=lambda: AddRemove(2))
    removePlayer.grid_forget()
    
    player1Frame.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=NW, pady=1)
    player2Frame.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=NW, pady=1)
    player3Frame.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=NW, pady=1)
    player4Frame.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=NW, pady=1)
    player5Frame.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=NW, pady=1)
    player6Frame.grid(column=1, row=6, sticky=NW, pady=1)
    player7Frame.grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=NW, pady=1)
    player8Frame.forget()
    player9Frame.forget()
    player10Frame.forget()
    player11Frame.forget()
    player12Frame.forget()
    player13Frame.forget()
    player14Frame.forget()

    buttonFrame.grid(column=1, row=8)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command=AddRemove(1)` will executed `AddRemove()` immediately even without clicking the button, and at that time `buttonFrame.grid(...)` is not yet called.  Change it to `command=lambda: AddRemove(1)`.  Same for `removePlayer` button.

Comment: @acw1668 I added lambda but now I get `addPlayer = Button(buttonFrame, text="Adicionar jogador", command=lambda: AddRemove(1))
NameError: name 'AddRemove' is not defined`

Comment: If you just change `command=AddRemove(1)` to `command=lambda: AddRemove(1)`, you should not get the error.  It works fine for me with the changes.  Better post your updated code as well.

Comment: I edited the post to add the entire buttons section and everything they interact with. I could send the entire code but it has over 340 lines. Is there any site I can paste the whole thing and just send a link?

Comment: The updated code is totally different from the original code.  What is the point of putting the code under `class Players()`?  The class is never used in your code.  Remove the class and put the code under the class to global scope.

Comment: The thing the leaps out for me is where you create `removePlayer` then issue a `removePlayer.grid_forget` any `removePlayer.grid_info` will return an empty dictionary.